# AWS Elasticsearch failing for _refresh request

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using `IAM user` ARN based access policy for AWS Elasticsearch. As per the documentation signing requests using AWS4Signer in RestHighLevelClient for elasticsearch.

All of the requests - `put/get/search` are working. However, `POST /_refresh` used at the end of saving a document is failing saying:

```
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"
```

The policy used is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountId:user/esUser"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:accountId:domain/myDomain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is any action I'm missing?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: No. AWS Elasticsearch doesn't seem to allowing this method. In every way it is returning error. Except this all other methods are working.